# Meaning of "your" in "Do you know your ABC?"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence-meaning, possessives

The [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary's article for "ABC"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/abc_1?q=ABC) contains the following example:

> Do you know your ABC?

I wonder why "your" is used in this example sentence. ABC in the stated meaning of *"all the letters of the alphabet, especially as they are learnt by children"* is the same for all people and therefore the same for all children.

So, what's the point in asking a child "Do you know **your** ABC?" if there is no "his", "her" or "their" ABCs?

Comment: It's idiomatic. You can just as well say that someone "knows their Shakespeare", for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Your* can indicate something specific that the people in the conversation are aware of or have a reference to, at least in casual conversation. The OALD entry for *[your](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/your)* includes

> 3. *(informal)* used to show that somebody/something is well known or often talked about
>
> > This is your typical English pub.
> >     (ironic, disapproving) You and your bright ideas!

[Macmillan's entry](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/your) has a similar sense:

> *informal* used for showing that something is a typical or normal example of its type
>
> > The National Television Awards is your typical glitzy event.
> >     This group is better than your average pop band.

*[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/your)* offers a more forceful definition:

> used with little or no meaning almost as an equivalent to the definite article *the*:
>
> > your typical teenager

Still, I would not use *your* in this sense in formal communications, and it is not interchangeable with *the* even in American English. It would be safer to say that *your* refers to someone's experience with something, and not that it is necessarily owned or associated with them. The effect of using *your* instead of *the* or another determiner is to suggest a shared knowledge or understanding of something. The effect is thus mildly ingratiating and socially leveling. My neighbor said *this isn't your typical January weather* to me because we *both* know that a forecast high of 68°F (20°C) is not normal for Washington, D.C. this time of year, and we can build a rapport based on that.

Answer (score 1):

*Your* is the possessive form of *you*.  *ABCs* is acting as a noun.

"To know one's ABCs" is an idiom, it means to know the alphabet, or to know the basics of a subject.

You can use any possessive pronoun in the expression.

Examples:

- *Does he know his ABCs?*
- *No, but my daughter knows her ABCs.*
- *I wish I knew my ABCs.*